# Ruby on Rails/Passenger with Apache2 - setting up sub domains

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, capistrano

I'm trying to configure Apache2 and mod_passenger so I can have one site at the root of the server `example.com/` and another totally different rails instance at `example.com/second`.

My `<VirtualHost>` context looks like this so far:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Name
    ServerName server.biz
    DocumentRoot /var/rails/current/public
    <Directory /var/rails/current/public>
            AllowOverride all
            Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

    # Logfile
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/server.biz.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/server.biz.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

If anyone has any ideas on how I can achieve this, or even a totally different approach to do it, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [mod_passenger documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html) you'll find the very answer to your question. From what your snippet shows you lack a couple of important directives to even get mod_passenger involved with your page at all. Check [this section](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_configuring_phusion_passenger) of the documentation to get a very exhausting overview on how to configure passenger to work.

When you got that and it happens that you can work with subdomains instead, I'd recommend to use two `<VirtualHost>` instances. Not sure if you can assign two or more`PassengerAppRoot` directives per context.

Comment: I managed to get it working using this. mod_passenger was actually working fine as it assumes a bunch of defaults. Thanks for this though.